# Nested arrays with objects, lodash meanBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, lodash

Can someone please help me understand how to make this work. Everytime I feel like I start to understand arrays and objects in Javascript it turns out that I still don't.

I'm trying to get the average of all prices in the following datastructure by using lodash `meanBy`

```
[
  {
    date: "2019-12-17",
    items: [
      { id: "1", state: "accepted", price: "90.5" },
      { id: "2", state: "rejected", price: "20.0" },
      { id: "3", state: "open", price: "10.5" },
    ]
  },
  {
    date: "2019-12-18",
    items: [
      { id: "4", state: "open", price: "450.0" },
      { id: "5", state: "rejected", price: "40.1" },
      { id: "6", state: "accepted", price: "50.9" },
    ]
  }
]
```

If you provide the answer, can you also please try to explain how you select something nested in items, because that's as far as I get before I get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case instead of selecting nested values, it's easier to flatten the items to a single array, and then apply `_.meanBy()`. In addition, the prices are strings, and not numbers, so you'll need to convert them.

Flatten the `items` to a single array with `Array.flatMap()`, and then use `_.meanBy()`, and get the numeric values of the prices:

```js
const data = [{"date":"2019-12-17","items":[{"id":"1","state":"accepted","price":"90.5"},{"id":"2","state":"rejected","price":"20.0"},{"id":"3","state":"open","price":"10.5"}]},{"date":"2019-12-18","items":[{"id":"4","state":"open","price":"450.0"},{"id":"5","state":"rejected","price":"40.1"},{"id":"6","state":"accepted","price":"50.9"}]}]

const result = _.meanBy(_.flatMap(data, 'items'), o => +o.price)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Another approach is to get the general average, by getting the average of each `items` array separately , and then getting the average of all averages.

```js
const data = [{"date":"2019-12-17","items":[{"id":"1","state":"accepted","price":"90.5"},{"id":"2","state":"rejected","price":"20.0"},{"id":"3","state":"open","price":"10.5"}]},{"date":"2019-12-18","items":[{"id":"4","state":"open","price":"450.0"},{"id":"5","state":"rejected","price":"40.1"},{"id":"6","state":"accepted","price":"50.9"}]}]

const result = _.meanBy(data, ({ items }) => _.meanBy(items, o => +o.price))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification in your post. I'd like to ask additionally where exactly you convert the string to a number. I've looked over the code a few times but I can't see it. 

Also what does the '+' do in ``o => +o.price``

Comment: You're welcome. The unary + converts the string to number.